lftp graceful case insensitive mget
I am trying to write an lftp_mget() shell function with a simple interface :
lftp_mget "FINANCE_SRV" "A-07B01522Y_Invoice_2023*.pdf" "/data/invoices/"

(arg1 is used to fetch server name & credentials from a known file, arg3 is remote path).
This covers 95% of use cases, but it has to be case-insensitive.
Also it shouldn't fail if no files are available for download.
Can mget be made to do this ? (it doesn't by default).
And mget || exit 0 would never fail, even in case of connection problem (or bad credentials) -> no go.
